# Прозрачность в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Как можно сделать прозрачным текстовое поле (там где печатать) в gedit(текстовый редактор в  Linux)? Например сделать его таким же прозрачным каким можно сделать терминал. Может кто подскажет другие текстовые редакторы (Vim и другие термальные не предлагать). Необходимо именно с настраиваемой прозрачностью ( с подсветкой синтаксиса разумеется)

Answer (score 1):

Как настроить прозрачность для любого приложения по отдельности см. [здесь](http://448dmg.ru/prozrachnost-okon-v-ubuntu-348)Рекомендую использовать текстовый редактор gedit с подсветкой синтаксиса там всё отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Композитный менеджер окон Compiz, не помогает? А должен.